# Is the Irrational Plane Path-Connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Is the set $I \times I \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, where $I = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ path connected?

It seems like it could be. Consider the path $\gamma : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $ given by $\gamma(t) = \left(t, (1 - t^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$. Fermat's last theorem guarantees $\gamma((0,1)) \subset I \times I$. Thus, $\gamma$ is a path of non-zero length contained in $I \times I$. Perhaps paths like $\gamma$ could be glued together to connect any two points of $I \times I$?

## Edit

As has been pointed out below, it is not the case that $\gamma((0,1)) \subset I \times I$. Clearly $\gamma(q) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$ when $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Fermat's theorem only guarantees that $\gamma((0,1)) \subset \mathbb{R} \times I$. I had in mind the arc given implicitly by the equation $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ for $x,y \in (0,1)$. While this arc will be a subset of $I \times I$, it is in fact totally disconnected.

Comment: Fermat's last theorem is a nice thought, but unfortunately $\gamma((0,1)) \nsubseteq I \times I$, because $I \times I$ is missing all points with rational $x$-coordinate, for instance.

Comment: If $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the projections onto the first and second coordinates, then $\alpha_1=\pi_1\circ \gamma$ and $\alpha_2=\pi_2\circ\gamma$ are continuous. Since $(0,1)$ is connected then its image by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are connected. This mean that they contain only one point.

Comment: I see now that the use of Fermat's last theorem was misguided. The arc composed of points $x, y \in (0,1)$ such that $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ certainly lives in $I \times I$, but is not connected. Meanwhile the arc I described contains points with rational coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$I\times I$ is not path connected (or connected, for that matter), because the projection $\pi(x,y)=x$ is a continuous map and $\pi[I\times I]$ is the disconnected set $I$.

In fact, in your candidate path, $\gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\left(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt[3]7}2\right)\notin I\times  I$.

On the other hand, $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\setminus(\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q)$ is path-connected, just like all complements of countable subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ are.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not even connected. Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&I\times I&\longrightarrow&\{0,1\}\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y>\frac12\\0&\text{ if }y<\frac12.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is continuous and $f(I\times I)=\{0,1\}$, which is disconnected.